# How to deal with multiplicity when checking if an arraylist is a subset

Tags: java, arraylist, subset, multiplicity

I have two `Arraylist` and I want to check if one is a subset of the other (ordering is not important in the comparison). 
The problem is: Lets say `Ar1={e,e,r}` and `Ar2={e,r,b,d}`. In my code it says `Ar1` is a subset. But I want it to say false, cause `Ar2` has only one e. How to do that?

```
public static void dostuff(String word1,String word2){
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String character : word1.split("")) {
        list1.add(character);
    }
    for (String character : word2.split("")) {
        list2.add(character);
    }

    boolean sub = list1.containsAll(list2) || list2.containsAll(list1);

    System.out.println(sub);
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly what you are doing. I'm assuming this is a theoretical example otherwise you could just do `boolean sub = word1.contains(word2) || word2.contains(word1)`?

Comment: No that doesn not work, cause it looks at the order of the letters and i dont want te order to matter.

Comment: that is fine, it would be worth editing your question to state that you don't want order to matter in the comparison.

Comment: Check my answer, I believe it does all the work you want without having to call the method twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself, please check of this is right, but i believe it is.

```
public static void dostuff(String word1, String word2) {
    boolean sub = false;

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < word1.length(); i++) {
        list1.add(word1.split("")[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < word2.length(); i++) {
        list2.add(word2.split("")[i]);
    }

    if (list1.size() >= list2.size()) {
        for (String i : list2) {
            if (list1.contains(i)) {
                list1.remove(i);
                list3.add(i);
            }
        }
        if (list2.containsAll(list3) && list2.size() == list3.size()) {
            sub = true;
        }
    } else if (list2.size() > list1.size()) {
        for (String i : list1) {
            if (list2.contains(i)) {
                list2.remove(i);
                list3.add(i);
            }
            if (list1.containsAll(list3) && list1.size() == list3.size()) {
                sub = true;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sub);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be what you want. Note that `list2.remove(elem)` returns `true` if an element was removed, and `false` if not.

```
public static boolean dostuff(String word1,String word2){
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list3;

    for (String character : word1.split("")) {
        list1.add(character);
    }

    for (String character : word2.split("")) {
        list2.add(character);
    }

    list3 = new ArrayList<>(list2);

    boolean isSubset = true;

    for (final String elem : list1) {
        if (!list2.remove(elem)) {
            isSubset = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isSubset) {
        return true;
    }

    for (final String elem : list3) {
        if (!list1.remove(elem)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: To make this answer perfect, create a third list which is a copy of `list2`, and do the same loop inside `list3` against `list1`. OP wants to check both ways.

Comment: Ah, he wants to check if either list1 is a subset of list2 OR if list2 is a subset of list1?

Comment: Indeed, look at his `||` expression.

Comment: One more thing, your return mechanic is broken. Use a boolean flag for the first loop and return true if it passes, otherwise carry on to the second loop.

Comment: Yes the 'or' is important. It does not matter even one is subset of the other or vica versa.

Comment: Sorry @Amine. Did the change a bit too quickly. :) Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Working Solution

Check [Demo](http://ideone.com/dxuepQ)

```
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
 {
    dostuff("eer","erbd");
 }

 public static void dostuff(String word1, String word2) {
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

   for (String character : word1.split("")) {
            list1.add(character);
        }

        boolean sub = true;
        for (String character : word2.split("")) {
            if (list1.remove(character)) {
               if (list1.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                sub = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sub);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note also that a mathematical, and java, set is unique, so be careful of using the term "subset".

You can use a frequency map to test if one list "has each element in another list, with the same or fewer occurrences". i.e. once you have your list you can convert it into a `Map<T, Integer>` to store the counts of each list element. The use of a map avoids mutating the original lists (which you would do if testing by removing elements from the master list as you encounter them):

```
public static <T> boolean isSublist(List<T> masterList, List<T> subList) {
    Map<T, Integer> masterMap = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    for (T t : masterList) masterMap.put(t, 1 + masterMap.getOrDefault(t, 0));

    Map<T, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    for (T t : subList) testMap.put(t, 1 + testMap.getOrDefault(t, 0));

    for(Map.Entry<T, Integer> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
        if (masterMap.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0) < entry.getValue()) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

`getOrDefault` is only available as of Java 8, but you can easily write your own method to take care of the same operation.

Comment: word1.contains(word2) ? What if word1 = erbd and word2 = erd. They are subset but contains will return false. Please remove

Comment: @Rohit. The original question did not specify if order was, or was not important - I included it as a (now answered) comment in my original question. Now removed, but the remainder of my answer is still valid.

Comment: Yes this does not work i tried this. the order of things mather here.

Comment: @johdoe - removed that part of the answer for you. The map method is fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Johdoe. The below logic may help you. you can optimize if you want.

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("e");
list1.add("a");
list1.add("r");

list2.add("e");
list2.add("r");
list2.add("b");
list2.add("d");
list2.add("a");
System.out.println("list2 " + list2);
System.out.println("list1 " + list1);

Set<Integer> tempList = new HashSet<Integer>();

System.out.println("  containsAll " + list2.containsAll(list1));
for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++) {
        if (list2.get(i).equals(list1.get(j))) {
            tempList.add(i);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(" tempList  " + tempList);
System.out.println("list 1 is subset of list 2  "
        + (tempList.size() == list1.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand that the order of the contents doesn't matter, you just want to know if all the characters of one string exists in another (with the same frequency) or vice versa.

Try this function, it'll check everything without having to call the method twice and without using streams:

```
public static boolean subsetExists(String s1, String s2) {
    String temp = s2.replaceAll(String.format("[^%s]", s1), "");
    char[] arr1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] arr2 = temp.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);

    boolean isSubset = new String(arr2).contains(new String(arr1));
    if (!isSubset) {
        temp = s1.replaceAll(String.format("[^%s]", s2), "");
        arr1 = temp.toCharArray();
        arr2 = s2.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr1);
        Arrays.sort(arr2);

        isSubset = new String(arr1).contains(new String(arr2));
    }
    return isSubset;
}
```

You don't have to bother turning your `String`s into `List`s.  What's happening is we're checking if all the letters in `s1` exist in `s2` or vice versa.

We removed characters that are not in `s1` from `s2` and stored that result in a temporary `String`. Converted both the temporary `String` and `s1` into `char[]`s.  We then sort both arrays and convert them back into `String`s.  We then can check if **NEW SORTED** temporary `String` `contains()` the **NEW SORTED** `s1`.  If this result is false, then we apply the same logical check from `s2` to `s1`.

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s1 = "eer";
    String s2 = "bderz";
    String s3 = "bderzzeee";

    System.out.println(subsetExists(s1, s2));
    System.out.println(subsetExists(s1, s3));
}

public static boolean subsetExists(String s1, String s2) {
    String temp = s2.replaceAll(String.format("[^%s]", s1), "");
    char[] arr1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] arr2 = temp.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);

    boolean isSubset = new String(arr2).contains(new String(arr1));
    if (!isSubset) {
        temp = s1.replaceAll(String.format("[^%s]", s2), "");
        arr1 = temp.toCharArray();
        arr2 = s2.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr1);
        Arrays.sort(arr2);

        isSubset = new String(arr1).contains(new String(arr2));
    }
    return isSubset;
}
```

Results:

```
false
true
```

Comment: Sorry this fails on the following. if s1=abjkgh and s2=abk then s2 is not a subset of s1 in your code. but it should be.

Comment: @johdoe I'm sorry, one of my original thoughts accounted for this.  Give me a moment and I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a couple of maps to store the frequency of each letter:

```
public static void dostuff(String word1, String word2) {
    Map<String, Long> freq1 = Arrays.stream(word1.split("")).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    Map<String, Long> freq2 = Arrays.stream(word2.split("")).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    System.out.println(contains(freq1, freq2) || contains(freq2, freq1));
}
```

Where the `contains` method would be as follows:

```
private static boolean contains(Map<String, Long> freq1, Map<String, Long> freq2) {
    return freq1.entrySet().stream().allMatch(
        e1 -> e1.getValue().equals(freq2.get(e1.getKey())));
}
```

Test:

```
dostuff("eer", "erbd"); // {r=1, e=2}, {b=1, r=1, d=1, e=1}, false

dostuff("erbed", "eer"); // {b=1, r=1, d=1, e=2}, {r=1, e=2}, true
```

The idea is to use java 8 streams to create the frequencies map, and then, stream the entry set of both maps to compare all the elements and their frequencies. If all entries match, then it means that the second list contains all the elements of the first list with the same frequencies, regardless of the order.

In case the result is `false` for the first list, the check is performed the other way round as well, as per the question requirements.